# Folder structure for AngularJS app with REST API

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I want to build an AngularJS application in which I want to use AngularJS for front end and REST API for back-end data. Please give me suggestions for directory structure **

Answer (score 0):

You can find multiple ways of structuring your project on the world wide web. This is one out of the millions examples out there. Try searching for 'best way to structure your Angular project'.

[image]

You can also find a more detailed explanation on this link: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating angular services for consuming your REST API, which will in turn be injected in your controllers.
For your directory structure I suggest one directory per module. For example :

-- navigation
   navigationCtrl.js
   navigationService.js

-- search
   searchService.js